# HTML5 Video background - IE error

Tags: jquery, css, html, video

For using a video as background on my webpage i use this code:

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background: url(images/bg/home.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
```

it works in safari, chrome, firefox and opera, but ie doen't support "object-fit: cover", so doesn't fill the screen totally, I have tried many solutions from the web and here on stackoverflow, but none of them works. 
- what to do?

Comment: You have a complete guide to do this at [this article](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video).

Comment: MS Edge doesn't support object-fit for video, but you can upvote to have this feature added. Link is -  https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-eleme

Answer (score 0):

Does this IE support HTML5?.If not try with latest version.